# most cost-effective route w.r.t. gas in a labelled graph

Tags: graphs, np-complete, dynamic-programming, polynomial-time, parameterized-complexity

Consider a car that can hold gas to travel a distance of $c \in N$ kilometers (its capacity) on a full tank that's initially empty. The car starts in node $s \in V$ of a graph. Each vertex $V_i$ of the graph has a gas station where the car can (not necessarily fully) refuel at price (i.e. cost) $p(V_i) \in R_{>0}$ per kilometer. Each edge $E_j$ has associated a distance $d_j \in N (d_j\le c)$ kilometers between its vertices. The goal is to travel to a target vertex $t$ at a minimum sum of costs for the refuels.

Question: Is this optimization problem polynomially solvable? Or is its decision version NP-complete?

To more formally express the cost (i.e. the objective function), we're looking for a path $P$ and an associated refueling schema $F$ where the $x$th vertex on the path is $V(P_x)$ and the $x$th refueling on the path is $F_x \in N$ so that the capacity constraint $c$ is met. The cost for refueling at vertex $V(P_x)$ is then $p(V(P_x))F_x$. We are to minimize $\Sigma p(V(P_x))F_x$

I hope and think the informal formulation is straightforward and won't lead to ambiguities under normal interpretations (the car is not allowed to run out of gas before reaching a vertex), whereas a more formal problem statement might be tedious.

Obviously, another variant where not each vertex has a gas station can be reduced to this variant by contracting vertices without a gas station or by setting the price in such vertices high enough.

If we can answer this question, interesting further research might be how its variants behave, namely with graphs of fixed treewidth or allowing negative prices $p_i$ or fractional distances $d_j$. If we can't find a polynomial algorithm for the main problem, can we then find one that's superpolynomial (say exponential) only in the size of the capacity $c$? (i.e. polynomial in the value of $c$. Going ahead a bit too much, such might be a nice example of a parameterized algorithm).

Comment: This seems to be pseudo-polynomial in the gas level of the car, at least. I mean, if the state transition diagram $[0,c]'\times V$, where $[0,c]'$ denotes the discrete states of the gas tank relevant for the problem, is of polynomial size, then we reduce to finding shortest paths in that graph. Perhaps look into certain knapsack formulations for more research in this direction.

Comment: The special case where $c=\infty$ can be solved in polynomial time.  At any point in a journey, you can summarize the state you are in as $\langle v,p\rangle$, where $v$ represents which vertex of the graph you are currently at, and $p$ is the cheapest price for gas seen so far along your journey.  Let $d(\langle v,p \rangle)$ be the distance from $\langle s,p(s) \rangle$ to $\langle v,p \rangle$, i.e., the cost of the cheapest journey that starts at $s$ and ends at $\langle v,p \rangle$, with zero gas left in the tank.  (It follows that it costs $gp$ more to end up with $g$ gas in the tank.)

Comment: Now you can do a variant of Dijkstra's algorithm on the state graph.  There are only quadratically many possible states, hence this runs in polynomial time.  Unfortunately, this doesn't work for finite $c$; we run into some knapsack-like difficulties.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is polynomial-time solvable.

A solution can be represented by a sequence of points $F = ((u_1, f_1), \dots, (u_k, f_k))$ where $u_i$ is a vertex and $f_i$ is the amount of refuel (possibly $0$) at the vertex.
Also, let $b_i$ be the gas amount before the refuel $i$, and $a_i = b_i + f_i$ be the gas amount after the refuel.

We show that there is an optimal solution that, in every refuel, either the gas tank was empty before the refuel or the gas tank is full after the previous refuel. That is,
$$\tag{*} \forall 1 \le i \le k, \; b_i = 0 \lor a_{i-1} = C$$
Proof: Suppose for the contrary, that the lexicographically smallest optimal solution doesn't satisfy the condition above. Let $i$ be the last refuel with a condition violation. There are two cases:

- Case $p(u_{i-1}) \ge p(u_i)$: we decrease the previous refuel and increase the current refuel by $b_i > 0$. The new solution is lexicographically smaller and the cost is equal to or better than the current solution, contradicting the assumption that the current solution is the smallest.
- Case $p(u_{i-1}) < p(u_i)$: we increase the previous refuel and decrease the current refuel by $C - a_{i-1} > 0$. The cost of the new solution is better than the current solution, contradicting the assumption that the current solution is optimal.

Let $d_{u,v}$ be the shortest path distance from $u$ to $v$ in the original graph. Define a graph $G'$ on vertices $\{ (u, 0), (u, C) \mid u \in V \}$ by edges:
$$
\begin{align}
e^1_{u,v} &= ((u, 0), (v, 0), d_{u,v} p(u)) & d_{u,v} \le C \\
e^2_{u,v} &= ((u, C), (v, C), d_{u,v} p(v)) & d_{u,v} \le C \\
e^3_{u,w,v} &= ((u, C), (v, 0), (d_{w,v} + d_{u,w} - C) p(w)) & d_{u,w}, d_{w,v} \le C \le d_{w,v} + d_{u,w}\\
e^4_u &= ((u, 0), (u, C), C p(u)) \\
\end{align}
$$

1. $e^1_{u,v}$: At $u$, refuel the amount just to make $v$, then move to $v$.
2. $e^2_{u,v}$: Move from $u$ to $v$, then refuel to the full capacity.
3. $e^3_{u,w,v}$: Move from $u$ to $w$, then refuel the amount just to make to $v$, then move to $v$.
4. $e^4_u$: At $u$, refuel to the full capacity.

The answer is the shortest path distance from $(s, 0)$ to $(t, 0)$.

Proof: Let $((u_1, f_1), \dots, (u_k, f_k))$ be the optimal solution, satisfying the condition (*).

We say a point $1 \le i \le k$ is a *stop* if $b_i = 0 \lor a_i = C$.
For a stop $i$, define $c_i = \begin{cases}0 & \text{ if } b_i = 0 \\ C & \text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$.

Let $d(x,y)$ to denote the shortest distance from $x$ to $y$ in $G'$, and let $D_i = d((u_1, 0), (u_k, c_k))$.
By induction, we prove $D_k + (a_k - c_k) p(u_k) \le \sum_{i=1}^k f_i p(u_i)$, assuming the last point is a stop.

Proof sketch for each case:

- $b_k = 0$ and $b_{k-1} = 0$: Use $e^1_{u_{k-1},u_k}$.
- $b_k = 0$ and $a_{k-2} = C$: First use $e^4_{u_{k-2}}$ if $b_{k-2} = 0$. Then use $e^3_{u_{k-2},u_{k-1},u_k}$.
- $a_{k-1} = C$ and $a_k = C$: First use $e^4_{u_{k-1}}$ if $b_{k-1} = 0$. Then use $e^2_{u_{k-1},u_k}$.

Comment: @AlbertHendriks I fixed my answer so it should be correct now (the proof sketch becomes more concrete, so I have some confidence). Also I implemented my answer in a program and it is returning correct answer in random cases.

Comment: @D.W. I added some more explanation to the constructed graph. Also expanded the proof for the concrete path construction (I'm not good at explaining concisely).
Re "multiple $w$'s", using the added terminology *stop*, $w$'s corresponds to non-stops. Due to the condition (*), non-stops cannot be adjacent. Your last case is covered by $e^3_{u,w,v}$.